# Suitable first-year experiment idea - stability of coordination complexes in TLC?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, coordination-compounds, chromatography

I'm a first-year in university and we have to carry out a "measurement" project next term. I'm fascinated by coordination chemistry (though I haven't taken the course yet), and while our equipment list is pretty limited it does include a thin-layer chromatography setup (and a colorimeter & a pH probe, which I would love to use if there was a way).

I was thinking of using TLC to look at the stability of different complexes (either different ligands or central metals), similar to the experiments in these papers:

- [Stability of mixed-ligand $\ce{zinc(II)}$ carboxylate complexes in thin-layer chromatography](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/226026267_Stability_of_mixed-ligand_zincII_carboxylate_complexes_in_thin-layer_chromatography)
- [Thin-layer chromatographic determination of the stability of complexes of substituted styrenes on silver nitrate-impregnated silica](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021967300840765)

However, I'm struggling to come up with examples of complexes that can be made easily (without a fume hood) and inexpensively. I'm not very knowledgable about this topic so I apologize if this is a bad question, I was just wondering if this seemed like a feasible yet worthwhile project given constraints in equipment/money and my knowledge. In previous years, people have mostly done biology or physics related projects so I'm a little doubtful if this idea—in particular, synthesizing a variety of complexes—is realistic. I'd appreciate any advice, specific or general! Thanks!

Comment: Ferrocene and acetyl ferrocene are the archetypal undergraduate examples.

Comment: @NotWoodward Thank you! I think we have those in our labs for the 2nd year student. I'm a little worried that it wouldn't be considered "novel", is there anyway to modify the project slightly?

Comment: You can replace iron with various other metals? There are many complexes you could buy/make really. I'm not sure the whole idea is novel anyway, nor would novel really be expected for an undergraduate.

Comment: @NotWoodward Thanks so much! Haha it definitely isn't a novel idea by any means, but "novel" was in the project description so I guess I'll try.